# Exponential Distribution: Accidents occur in a factory at the rate of 3 per week.

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

Accidents occur in a factory at the rate of 3 per week. Assume that accidents happen randomly and independently of each other.

> What is the mean time(in weeks) to the first accident?

For this question, the mean is $u=\frac{1}{λ}$.
Which equals $u=\frac{1}{3}=.33$.

> What is the variance of the time(in weeks) to the first accident?

Now, apparently I got the answer wrong for this question. Here's what I did, and I would love some feedback on what I did wrong. 
The variance $v$ for the Exponential Distribution is $v=\frac{1}{λ^2}$.
Which equals $\frac{1}{λ^2}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{3})^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{9}}=9$
So I concluded that the variance is $9$. But apparently it is wrong according to the automatic online grading system.

Comment: Your answer should be $\frac 19$, not $9$. Note that you replaced $\lambda$ with $\frac 1 \lambda$ incorrectly.

Comment: Isn't $λ$ equal to $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: The answer below gives a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{3}$ does not imply that $\lambda=\frac{1}{3}$. Instead $\lambda = 3$, and so

$$v=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac{1}{9}.$$

Comment: OH! I understand now. $λ$ was always $3$. I just got confused because the mean formula has a fraction in it. Thank you!